# onclick="copy(this)" not working javascript

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

I have a table and 10 rows When I copy this image src. It copied the last src

HTML

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tbody>
        @foreach($medias as $media)
            <tr>
                <td class="align-middle">{{ $media->id }}</td>
                <td class="align-middle"><img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$media->image) }}" class="image" alt="image" width="100" height="50"></td>
                <td class="align-middle">
                    <form action="{{ route('admin.medias.destroy', $media->id) }}" method="post">
                        @csrf
                        @method('DELETE')
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">del</button>
                    </form>
                </td>
                <td class="align-middle"><a onclick="copy(this)" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">copy</a></td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS

```
<script>
    function copy () {
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(document.getElementsByClassName('image').src);
    }
</script>
```

I copied `undefined`.

**Note:** This code has no errors in the output.

Comment: `copy()` doesn't accept any arguments and always copies `document.getElementById('image')` (Of which there should only be one in the document since Ids are required to by unique)

Comment: What does an `<img>` got to do with this `<table>`?

Comment: `this` will represent the `A` element, not image, your `copy()` function doesn't accept any arguments, and getting source of an image with id `image`

Comment: What is the solution?

Comment: You cannot use the same "id" value on more than one element.

Comment: I see `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot repeat Id inside DOM. So you can set up id dynamically, btw you need to pas the element to your copy().

Try the next code and let me know if it is working. I didn't test it, but it should work

**Blade**

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tbody>
        @foreach($medias as $media)
            <tr>
                <td class="align-middle">{{ $media->id }}</td>
                <td class="align-middle"><img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$media->image) }}" id="image-{{$media->id}}" alt="image" width="100" height="50"></td>
                <td class="align-middle">
                    <form action="{{ route('admin.medias.destroy', $media->id) }}" method="post">
                        @csrf
                        @method('DELETE')
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">del</button>
                    </form>
                </td>
                <td class="align-middle"><a onclick="copy('image-{{$media->id}}')" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">copy</a></td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
    function copy (element) {
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(document.getElementsById(element).src);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I see this error https://i.stack.imgur.com/05tj3.png

Comment: I have edited the original, look up  onclick `<td class="align-middle"><a onclick="copy('image-{{$media->id}}')" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">copy</a></td>`

Answer (score 0):

**Example A** is more true to the OP layout. **Example B** was started before the question was updated. One important thing you should remember is that you cannot have any identical `#id`s they must be unique, so `img#image` is `img.image` in the examples.

**Details are commented in both examples**

### Example A

```js
// Bind the <tbody> to the click event
document.querySelector('tbody').onclick = copyPath;

function copyPath(e) {
  // Stop link from jumping
  e.preventDefault();
  // Reference the link user clicked
  const clk = e.target;
  /*
  If the tag user clicked has .copy class...
  ...find the closest <tr> from clk...
  ...then find .image in <tr>...
  ...get .image src value and add it to clipboard
  */
  if (clk.matches('.copy')) {
    const image = clk.closest('tr').querySelector('.image');
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(image.src);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<main class='container'>
  <section class='row'>
    <div class='col'>
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="align-middle"></td>
            <td class="align-middle"><img class='image' src="https://placem.at/places?w=100&h=50&random=1&txt=1&txtclr=fc0" alt="image" width="100" height="50"></td>
            <td class="align-middle">
              <form action="about:blank" method="post">
                <button class="delete btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
              </form>
            </td>
            <td class="align-middle"><a href='!#' class="copy btn btn-sm btn-info">Copy Image Path</a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="align-middle"></td>
            <td class="align-middle"><img class='image' src="https://placem.at/places?w=100&h=50&random=2&txt=2&txtclr=fc0" alt="image" width="100" height="50"></td>
            <td class="align-middle">
              <form action="about:blank" method="post">
                <button class="delete btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
              </form>
            </td>
            <td class="align-middle"><a href='!#' class="copy btn btn-sm btn-info">Copy Image Path</a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="align-middle"></td>
            <td class="align-middle"><img class='image' src="https://placem.at/places?w=100&h=50&random=3&txt=3&txtclr=fc0" alt="image" width="100" height="50"></td>
            <td class="align-middle">
              <form action="about:blank" method="post">
                <button class="delete btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
              </form>
            </td>
            <td class="align-middle"><a href='!#' class="copy btn btn-sm btn-info">Copy Image Path</a></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class='row'>
    <div class='col'>
      <textarea class='form-control' rows='3' cols='50' placeholder='Paste Here'></textarea>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

### Example B

```js
// Collect <figure> into an array
const frames = [...document.querySelectorAll('figure')];

// On each <figure>...
frames.forEach(fig => {
  // Get the src of <img>
  let path = fig.firstElementChild.src;
  // Reference the <a>
  let link = fig.lastElementChild.firstElementChild;
  // Add data-src attribute with the value of path to the link
  link.setAttribute('data-src', path);
});

// Bind the click event to <section>
document.querySelector('section').onclick = copyPath;

function copyPath(e) {
  // Stop link from jumping
  e.preventDefault();
  // Reference the link user clicked
  const clk = e.target;
  /* 
  If the tag clicked has attribute [data-src]...
  ...add the link's data-src value to clipboard
  */
  if (clk.hasAttribute('data-src')) {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(clk.dataset.src);
  }
}
```

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px
}

figure {
  margin: 0
}

figcaption {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h3>Click a link then right click + <u>P</u>aste or <kbd>Ctrl/⌘</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> to the <code>&lt;textarea&gt;</code> below:</h3>
<section>
  <figure>
    <img src='https://placem.at/places?w=160&h=90&random=1&txt=1&txtclr=fc0'>
    <figcaption><a href='!#'>Image Source</a></figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src='https://placem.at/places?w=160&h=90&random=2&txt=2&txtclr=fc0'>
    <figcaption><a href='!#'>Image Source</a></figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src='https://placem.at/places?w=160&h=90&random=3&txt=3&txtclr=fc0'>
    <figcaption><a href='!#'>Image Source</a></figcaption>
  </figure>
</section>
<textarea rows='3' cols='65' placeholder='Paste Here'></textarea>
```